# Long Look Notification: dynamic interface doesn't show, only static interface

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I was trying to test our rich push notification on a real Apple Watch. Our WatchKit extension implemented both the static interface and the dynamic interface for Long Look. But every time I sent a push notification, only the **static** interface is shown, instead of the dynamic interface.

This shouldn't be related to the performance of our dynamic interface (Watch OS will fallback to the static interface, if the dynamic one takes too long to load). The Apple Watch showed the static interface almost immediately.

How to display the **dynamic** interface of Long Look?

Comment: I need help with notifications in real watch. Please give me some guidance.

Comment: I am trying to send local notification to watch app from iPhone. I am not able to recieve local notification in watch. Please give me some information

Comment: @iOSdev sorry I haven't tried with local notification yet. Maybe post a new question?

Comment: Can you try to display some uilocalnotification and tell me how the watch is diplaying it?

Comment: @iOSdev sorry, no. I don't have the time and need for it now.

Comment: please help me atleast I want to know how the notification is shown in watch . means uilocalnotification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **battery** related. If the Apple Watch has less than 10% battery and is not being charged, it will skip dynamic interfaces automatically and only display the static interfaces.

The solution is to connect the charger :)

Answer (score 1):

When you first get the notification prompt on your watch and you activate it, do you see the dynamic notification? Make sure you have the "sound" field set in your APNS payload otherwise you wont get the sound/tap.

In this (I think) [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987642/apple-watch-dynamic-long-look-not-shown-when-push-opened-from-notification-cen/30042236#30042236) it seems as though we're unable to access dynamic notifications from the notification hub. The user will only see the dynamic notification if they check their notification immediately after they receive it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you put it down onto your desk, the watch will detect that users are not wearing on that. And it will display the static interface. Once, you put it on your wrist, it will display the dynamic interface.

Answer (score 0):

Another [related issue asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554243/dynamic-notification-interface-will-only-work-if-the-watch-app-extension-was-o) which I found to be my case, is that the dynamic notification is only shown if the accompanying watch app is opened at least once from the watch app launcher.