# Apple Watch: dynamic Long Look not shown, when push opened from Notification Center

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I implemented a custom **dynamic** Long Look for push notifications on the Apple Watch. This dynamic long look is shown correctly, when I immediately raise my arm after receiving a push notification. However, if I respond later, and tap on the push notification from within Notification Center on the Watch, only the **static** long look is shown.

Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? How are your dynamic long looks behaving?

---

For clarity here are the **steps to reproduce**.

This will bring up the **dynamic** long look:

1. I receive a push notification on the Watch
2. I immediately raise my arm to see the push

But this will only bring up the **static** long look:

1. I receive a push notification on the Watch
2. Ignore it at first. After one minute activate the Watch
3. Drag down from top of the Watch face to bring up Notification Center
4. Tap on the ignored push

Answer (score 2):

I suspect all notifications that are accessed through the notifications center of the watch are by default static.

I can't find any documentation to confirm this though. Would be a major bummer if that's the case.

Comment: I'm suspecting that too, which would be quite sad... Are your apps also behaving like this on your Watch?

Comment: Yep. The annoying part is that I also have 4 custom actions with the notification that are directly related to the custom payload. The static notification also shows the 4 actions which can be confusing I'm sure.

Comment: same here - its a bummer

Comment: apple's own apps like activities, calendar and so own actually display the dynamic interface if opened from notification centre - sad thing - is there some official documentation about it?

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same behaviour on my Apple Watch (running WatchOS 2). That is quite sad, since Apple apps are showing the dynamic interface also when accessed from the notification hub

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same problem and it is pretty frustrating because like Sohail my action buttons refer to the dynamic long look notification content. I dont know if I get [the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html) right here but the following lines sound like the proof to me that apple won´t show your dynamic long look notifications from the notification center:

> Use the static notification interface to define a simple version of your custom notification interface. The purpose of a static interface is to provide a fallback interface in the event that your WatchKit extension is unable to configure the dynamic interface in a timely manner. **The interface is also displayed in Notification Center.**

In the first place I thought this means the notification center just shows the static notification interface in it´s "main table view" but this is not the case. The notification center itself only shows the notification alert message and not the whole interface. So I think what they mean in the documentation is: "The interface is also displayed when opening notifications from the notification center"