# Watchkit Dynamic Notification appear only once

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I am currently programming an application for AppleWatch.

I want to develop dynamics notifications to display some informations on the watch that statics notifications can not handle.
However, Dynamics notifications appear only if i look my watch when it thrills. If i open my notification from the notification center, it is a static notification which appears.

Is it normal ?

Comment: It seems that this is the expected behaviour. And yes, this is pretty sad. Also, let me point you to this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987642/apple-watch-dynamic-long-look-not-shown-when-push-opened-from-notification-cen/30042236#30042236